# dlopen'd SO's conflict when unloaded

Tags: c++, regex, boost, shared-libraries, dlopen

I have two .so files that statically link boost regex. each of those so's are plugins that get dlopen'd by my main executable. It seems that when I unload one of them, it causes out of bound reads in the other so.

My theory is that when one so is unloaded, the other one's copy of boost is actually referencing stuff in the unloaded memory space of the first. To try to fix this, I've tried linking them with -Bsymbolic and -Bsymbolic-functions, to no avail. Any recommendations on what I should do here?

I also noted that switching to std regex in some places helped reduce valgrind error output, but we cant fully make the switch because there are features of boost regex that we need.

I'm using boost 1.61. I'll try upgrading to 1.66 if doing so is feasible.

Comment: That is really interesting and unexpected. I'm guessing that what you are doing is fairly complex. Could you use a custom allocator in one of the instances - there might be lots of passing around - to test your theory? I think it does sound like there is something cross-allocated here.

Comment: I could give that a shot, but there will be *a lot* of noise. The errors seem to be centered around the regex object_cache so I might be able to filter it that way

Comment: It reminds me of https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xVT1y0xWgww, but it is not clear from your question whether globals are involved or not.

Comment: Are there some global symbols from boost regex exported in SOs?

Comment: there are some global symbols in the so's in question that use boost regex. I'll try to provide more context when i have access to the codebase tomorrow at work

Comment: I think there are two options: 1. (in my opinion the cleanest, but haven't tried it with boost.regex yet so cannot say whether there are some pitfalls) boost.regex should be a shared library, because it has globals/singletons - that way the singletons aren't constructed/destructed twice. 2. you should compile with `-fvisibility=hidden` ( https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility ) which requires some changes in code, leads to every shared library having its own version of object_cache, but at least the program doesn't crash.